# How Can I Parse And Order This Date Format In Javascript ("10/10/2010 13")?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have an array of hourly date data strings in the format below.  How can I parse it into a Javascript Date Object and then order it either by ascending or descending?  The last two digits are the hour of day, out of 24.

```
["01/26/2014 01", "01/26/2014 16", "01/26/2014 19", "01/23/2014 22", "01/25/2014 09"]
```

Comment: new Date("01/26/2014 01" + ":00:00")

Comment: Use what @dandavis said to create the `Date` objects and then look here for how to sort dates:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690035/sort-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: Not tested much :-) (( at work ))

```
var a = ["01/26/2014 01", "01/26/2014 16", "01/26/2014 19", "01/23/2014 22", "01/25/2014 09"];
var b = [];
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  var dt = new Date(a[i] + ":00");
   b.push( dt );
}

console.log(b.sort());
console.log(b.sort().reverse());
```

Answer (score 1):

This library will help you: http://momentjs.com/. Read format section.

You could do something like this.

```
var formated_date = moment(your_js_var).format("D/M/YY H");
```

Comment: Please do not submit link-only answers. This should have been a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newDateArray = [];

for(var i=0;i<oldDateArray.length;i++)
{
  var d = new Date(oldDateArray[i]+":00");
  newDateArray.push(d);

}

newDateArray.sort();
```

Seems to work on my end.